# How do I configure phoenix to use sockets with postgresql

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

PostgreSQL supports using unix sockets rather than TCP sockets. How do I configure the following block to use unix sockets.

```
# Configure your database
config :my_app, Sample.Repo,
  adapter: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres,
  database: "ecto_simple",
  username: "postgres",
  password: "postgres"
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure Postgrex (The Elixir PostgreSQL driver which Ecto uses) doesn't support connecting via Unix sockets.

Comment: @Dogbert After looking through some docs, I think you might be right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of March 2018, Postgrex now supports connecting via sockets.

This can be done by supplying a `socket` or `socket_dir` option. Here's the [changelog](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/ad6310e860165358798b842e5b36e24a4f2aaf3f/CHANGELOG.md) from where I picked this up and the [source code](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/postgrex/blob/257389dc5b0c80491f96a835b3a8e465891110b3/lib/postgrex.ex) where you can see an exhaustive list of all options.

**From the source code:**

- `:socket_dir` - Connect to Postgres via UNIX sockets in the given directory;
    The socket name is derived based on the part. This is the preferred method
    for configuring sockets and it takes precedence over the hostname. If you are
    connecting to a socket outside of the Postgres convention, use `:socket` instead;
- `:socket` - Connect to Postgres via UNIX sockets in the given path.

This is especially useful (I suppose) if you're on AppEngine which requires you to connect through an SQL proxy through localhost (127.0.01) which works only through a proxy connection.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL prefers unix sockets to TCP sockets on the grounds of performance and privacy. If not already available: TCP can be enabled on the server if you follow simple documentation and have access to do so.

The avenue of client connection is set via environment variables, in particular: PGHOST. From experience drivers such as libpq expect to work that way - it would be shocking if Postgrex did not.
See: https://hexdocs.pm/postgrex/Postgrex.html

The value to supply in PGHOST varies according to the configuration of the server as seen in the file: "postgresql.conf".

It is possible that you may need to create a directory for sockets and set permissions.  The following should help: http://iamvery.com/2013/06/17/postgresapp-with-unix-socket.html

To get a more precise answer you will need to mention your operating system and version; also your version of PostgreSQL.